# UITableViewCell outside viewing area blank till I scroll down and then back up when I use OHAttributedLabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am using an OHAttributedLabel within my UITableViewCells to display some text partly in regular font and partly in italics. My tableview rows are structured such that 8 rows are displayed on the screen.

When I scroll down the 9th cell appears to be empty. Only when I scroll down far enough suc h that the ninth cell is out of the view and then scroll back up is when the text in the 9th cell is displayed.

I noticed that when I use the textLabel property of UITableViewCell I do not have this problem. Can someone throw insight into why I am seeing such behavior using OHAttributedLabel and how to fix it?